# How to update view when model data source changes?

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qabstracttablemodel, qt5.5

I have a class which inherits from `QAbstractTableModel`, which simply points along to a separate class for the views to access data information as follows:

```
    #include "QAbstractTableModel"
    class MyModel : public QAbstractTableModel
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        MyModel(QObject* parent = 0) {}

        void setDataSet(std::shared_ptr<dataset> dataset) {  
            beginResetModel(); 
            dataset_ = dataset;
            endResetModel();
        }

        int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const { return dataset_->rowCount(); }

        int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const { return dataset_->colCount(); }

        QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
        {
            if (role == Qt::DisplayRole) {
                return dataset_->data( index.row(), index.column() );
            }
            return QVariant();
        }

    private:
    std::shared_ptr<DataSet> dataset_;
    };
```

The underlying dataset will change often, and therefore I need the model to tell the view that it needs to completely redraw itself. The dataset may have different and more columns, rows, entries etc.

The above only works when the column count is different from the previous dataset, otherwise the table continues displaying the data from before.

Is there something different I should do here? All other sources point to the above calls to `beginResetModel()` and `endResetModel()`, but it doesn't work. These calls should tell all views that they need to redraw. I've thought about `dataChanged()`, but that seems like an odd workaround (I could have more columns than the prior dataset) for resetting the view.

Comment: In the code you posted, `beginResetModel()` and `endResetModel()` are only being called when you call `setDataSet()`. So, that's the only time that the view is being notified that something in the DataSet changed. I presume that you are only calling this function when a completely new dataset is applied, not just when something within the existing data changed, correct? If that's the case, there's your problem. You need to notify also when individual rows/columns or whatever within your DataSet have changed.

Comment: Suppose that for now, existing data in a dataset will not change, only the dataset itself. What I'm seeking is a way for the QTableView to ditch it's current representation and start again.

Comment: That's weird then, because calling endResetModel() should trigger a complete refresh of the entire view. If you put in debug breakpoints at endResetModel(), break when it hits that, then put a breakpoint in data, you should see after you call endResetModel() that data is called repeatedly afterwards (number of times should be equivalent to rows * columns * number of roles). Is that not the case?

Comment: Ah, that is the case. I followed your steps and it was calling for data(), which implied the underlying data hadn't changed. I was using qrand() with the same seed set. Changing the seed, it works a treat. Thanks!